# c# - Closing browse dialog causes form to close

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dialog

I have a form which is displayed through: `ShowDialog()`.
The form doesn't have `CancelButton` specified.

When I open a `BrowseDialog` from the form and then close the `BrowseDialog`, the form is also closed. How can I prevent this from happening?

*When the "browse"-button is clicked:*

```
browseDialog.SelectedPath = projectLocation.Text;
browseDialog.ShowDialog();

if (browseDialog.SelectedPath != "")
{
      projectLocation.Text = browseDialog.SelectedPath;
}
```

*When the "cancel"-button of the form is clicked:*

```
Close();
```

Comment: Show us some code. You probably call Form.Close somewhere...

Comment: WinForm project with a Form on which you have a 'FolderBrowserDialog ? fyi : I cannot replicate the behavior you describe using VS Studio 2010 beta 2 compiling against .NET FrameWork 3.5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would guess that the button you use to show the BrowseDialog has its DialogResult set to something other than None.

If this is not the case, please post some code.

Comment: Oh lol, that was it. I didn't even think of the Browse-button being set to Cancel. Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: Yeah, can happen if you copy-paste controls.

Comment: HAHAHA!  That was my issue too.  Thanks for the answer.  I will be much more careful during copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

in your onclosing event from your browser dialog, do a check on the sender arg to see which dialog is requesting the close and if it's not the browser dlg, set e.Cancel = true

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this when I had a similar issue, ensure your parent form is not setting ITS dialog result, because once the event to call the modal dialog is done, the parent form will close if it's set to something other than none.