# Cancelling folder browser dialog closes the parent form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this method in my form:

```
    private void getProjLocation() 
    {
       FolderBrowserDIalog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
       DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();
       if(result == DialogResult.OK) 
       {
        string ProjLocation = fbd.SelectedPath;
       }
    }
```

The problem is, when someone opens the folder browser dialog and cancels it by clicking the "x" button at the top right corner, it causes the parent form to close. 
What I've tried so far:

```
  if(result == DialogResult.OK) 
  {
   string ProjLocation = fbd.SelectedPath;
  } else {
   return;
  }
```

Return gave the exact same result: closed the parent form. The only relevant post I found was this one [c# - Closing browse dialog causes form to close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998817/c-sharp-closing-browse-dialog-causes-form-to-close) , but it didn't help, because the solution given is already implemented in my form and it's still the same.

The question is, what is causing the parent form to close and how can I prevent it?

Comment: What is calling `getProjLocation`? Almost certainly, you're already in the closing process of your form or some of your own code closes the form after `getProjLocation` returns.

Comment: Yes, I close the form after getProjLocation returns, but by setting breakpoints I figured out that the form closes BEFORE getProjLocation returns. The form closes right after cancelling the folder browser dialog, or return.

Comment: Please show us the entire code behind your button.

Comment: may b you are not cancling the form close after getting the right result because it is possible that you initiated the form close then a dialog appears if you select some thing then you need to cancel that else let the parent cancel lolz

Comment: Show the code where you call getProjLocation()